# Create a form that passes user input to another form

Tags: javascript

I need to create a form showing the different properties for an existing object that I have.

Depending on the input field that the user enters, that input should update the object values. For example, say you have an object called `car` with the following values:

```
brand:"Porsche", 
model:"GT3", 
year:2004, 
colour:"White"
```

Using your form, the user would be able to enter `Black` to update the color of the Porsche or enter `Cayenne` to update the model.

I need to write this in javascript. I know how to get the user input but how do I pass that information to another form and also update the output of that form?

I have to output that information, I've created a `div` to hold the content. I`m still a student and this has me confused.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

```js
const car = {
  brand: 'Porche',
  model: 'GT3',
  year: 2004,
  color: 'white'
}

// update html content that describes your car
const updateHtmlContent = obj => {
  const brand = document.querySelector('#brand span');
  const model = document.querySelector('#model span');
  const year = document.querySelector('#year span');
  const color = document.querySelector('#color span');

  // update corresponding html elements
  brand.textContent = obj.brand;
  model.textContent = obj.model;
  year.textContent = obj.year;
  color.textContent = obj.color;
}

// update your car object based on the input and the call html update function
// triggered by button click
const updateCarContent = obj => {
  // get input fields
  const brandInp = document.querySelector('#brandInp');
  const modelInp = document.querySelector('#modelInp');
  const yearInp = document.querySelector('#yearInp');
  const colorInp = document.querySelector('#colorInp');

  // update car properties only if the corresponding field is not empty
  if (brandInp.value !== '') { obj.brand = brandInp.value; }
  if (modelInp.value !== '') { obj.model = modelInp.value; }
  if (yearInp.value !== '') { obj.year = yearInp.value; }
  if (colorInp.value !== '') { obj.color = colorInp.value; }

  // clear input fields
  brandInp.value = '';
  modelInp.value = '';
  yearInp.value = '';
  colorInp.value = '';

  updateHtmlContent(obj);
}

updateHtmlContent(car);

// get submit button and click event listener to it that will trigger the update function
const submitBtn = document.querySelector('#submit');
submitBtn.addEventListener('click', event => {
  updateCarContent(car);
});
```

```html
<p id="brand">brand: <span></span></p>
<p id="model">model: <span></span></p>
<p id="year">year: <span></span></p>
<p id="color">color: <span></span></p>

<label for="brandInp">brand: </label>
<input type="text" id="brandInp" />
<br />

<label for="modelInp">model: </label>
<input type="text" id="modelInp" />
<br />

<label for="yearInp">year: </label>
<input type="text" id="yearInp" />
<br />

<label for="colorInp">color: </label>
<input type="text" id="colorInp" />
<br />

<button id="submit">Update</button>
```

Comment: Thank you, will take some time to understand but will keep practicing with this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick example of how you might get started: creating a couple of forms and then updating values from one form to another.

I'm intentionally keeping this code snippet as small as possible (what we call a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). It sounds as if the reading/writing values in javascript is the part that has you confused, and so that's the part I'm really focusing on.

```js
var oldMake = document.querySelector('#f1 input[name=make]');
var newMake = document.querySelector('#f2 input[name=make]');
newMake.value = oldMake.value + ' (add something)';
```

```html
<form id='f1'>
<input type='text' name='make' value='Porsche'/>
<input type='text' name='model' value='911'/>
</form>

<form id='f2'>
<input type='text' name='make'/>
<input type='text' name='model'/>
</form>
```

Comment: A bit to advanced for me at this point of time but thank you I will make a note of this and research more about it.